# Deep learning model to predict the actual input values

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoder

I have some observed parameters to be used as input to the deep learning model. This problem comes from the wireless field where we transmit $x$. The channel $h$ is random in nature. The received signal values $y$ are estimated at the receiver but because of the corruption from $h$, these $y$ values are not the correct transmitted values $x$. Here $x,y \in [-1,1]$ and $h \in Z^+$. Because each time we receive $y$, $h$ gets estimated as well to remove the corruption from $y$ and deduce $x$. The problem is that the estimation is not perfect so we always get $x$ in errors. I want to use a deep learning model like autoencoder to input many time-spaced observations of $h$ and $y$ and the corresponding true sequences $x$ as output for a specific location. Once I have the trained model I can test it with new sets and find the accuracy or probability of error.
Could someone give me a hint on this?

Comment: I would say probably you want a Deep Belief Network that uses Restricted Boltzman Machines

Comment: Thanks, Tiago, I read about RBM after you commented but I couldn't understand why you recommended that if you can elaborate more. The dataset I have contains the input and output already so why do I need unsupervised learning?